# Pseudoinverse with positive solutions

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, pseudoinverse

I'm not a mathematician but the *engineering* problem I'm considering is more of a mathematical question, that's why I post it here:

Consider the matrices $M$ ($n \times 1$), $T$ ($n \times m$) and $F (m \times 1)$, and:
$$
    M = TF
$$
I solved for $F$ using the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse. For this special case (where $T$ has full rank), $F$  is simply
$$
    F = T^+M=T^T (TT^T)^{-1}M
$$
with $T^+$ the pseudo-inverse.

However, I want to find only $F \geq 0$. Is there a similar (simple) way to find $F$? Is it a classical problem? There is an infinite amount of solutions $F$, but I want to find $F$ that e.g. minimises the norm of $F$ (like the pseudo-inverse), or e.g. the sum of $F$.

Please let me know if the question is clear or if I need to be more precise

Comment: You can add any element from $\ker T$ to your $F$ without violating the equation - just find a suitable element from $\ker T$ such that adding it to $T^\dagger M$ makes $F$ nonnegative.

Comment: How would I go about finding a suitable element from $\text{ker }T$ that makes $F$ nonnegative? And how do I make sure that norm of $F$ is minimal?

Comment: That is very dependent on $T$. In general you can look for algorithms to find a basis for $\ker T$ (if $n$ and $m$ are small). Then you can do some linear programming to find a suitable combination of basis vectors.

Comment: I was using linear programming in Matlab with the command [fmincon](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html). However, I was wondering if there is a general, simple solution (like $T^T(TT^T)^{-1}$ for the pseudo-inverse) for $F \geq 0$

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Such a solution might not even exist.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I wanted to prevent using unnecessary computational resources with fmincon, but if there is no other way around it, I'll have to

Comment: Note that linear programs are much better suited for `linprog`. It's faster because it's specialized on it. For even better performance, you could have a look at packages such as SDPT3 etc. The vanilla MATLAB isn't particularly good at optimization.

Comment: I don't really have a choice because this optimisation problem is a very small part of a large control system in Simulink, but thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: There is no formula, even though it is not 100% clear what you want. I guess you want sth like $\min \lVert M-TF \rVert$ subject to $F\geq 0$. This is a convex optimization problem and there are standard solvers available. You need a non-linear solver like CVX or, you could also you the optimization toolbox, in particular fmincon would do a good job.

Comment: (A very late response, but for everyone else's benefit) You're looking to solve a [non-negative least squares problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares).
In MATLAB, you can use `lsqnonneg`.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, the target matrix $\mathbf{T}$ has full column rank. Therefore the null space $\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)$ is trivial. Therefore the least squares solution is unique and given by the point
$$
 F = \mathbf{T}^{+}M = \left( \mathbf{T}^{*} \, \mathbf{T} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{T}^{*} M.
$$

There is but one solution $F$. Options to compute $\mathbf{T}^{+}$ via the SVD, or $\left( \mathbf{T}^{*} \, \mathbf{T} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{T}^{*}$ through conventional means.